# init with csv file instead of static values

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, object, init

I'm quite new to python... and I'd like to change a static approach reading input parameters to a more dynamic one, reading the input parameters from a .csv-file instead. I changed it from _old to _new as follows... but it doesn't worked out! Would be nice if someone could help me.

physics_old.py

```
class Box(object):

    def __init__(self, depth=5, width=10, height=3, density=7):

        # Dimensions
        self.depth = depth 
        self.width = width 
        self.height = height 
        self.density = density
```

sim_old.py

```
# Initialise instance, empty brackets for default see physics_old.py
Cuboid = Object(depth=6, width=12, height=2, density=7.5)
```

I want to change this static approach to a more dynamic one, reading the input parameters from a .csv-file. I changed it to the following...

physics_new.py

```
class Box(object):

    def __init__(self, box_data):

        labels = ['depth', 'width', 'height', 'density']

        # Import csv file
        data = pd.read_csv(box_data, skiprows=1, sep=';', index_col=False, names=labels)

        # Dimensions
        self.depth = data['depth'] 
        self.width = data['width']
        self.height = data['height']
        self.density = data['density']
```

sim_new.py

```
# Initialise instance, empty brackets for default see physics_new.py
Cuboid = Object(data)
```

Comment: `data['depth']` These will be all rows values of depth col, however you were using only a single value before

Comment: Hi, did you tried to print 'data' variable? Did it return correctly? Also I've doubts on creating objects this way. You are assigning list to a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code as:

```py
class Box(object):

    def __init__(self, box_data):

        labels = ['depth', 'width', 'height', 'density']

        # Import csv file
        data = pd.read_csv(box_data, skiprows=1, sep=';', index_col=False, names=labels)

        for _,row in data.iterrows():

           # Dimensions
           self.depth = row['depth'] 
           self.width = row['width']
           self.height = row['height']
           self.density = row['density']
```

> But you will be left with last row value in `self.*variables*`. change your code flow